# Max Heap Insert Function Implementation C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, heap, max-heap

I'm trying to insert key values into heap. I'm using TestUnit.cpp for errors. I got these errors:

Assert failed.
Expected:<[(10,100),(7,70),(6,60),(5,50),(2,20),(1,10),(3,30),(4,40)]>
Actual:<[(7,70),(5,50),(6,60),(4,40),(2,20),(1,10),(3,30),(10,100)]>

Assert failed.
Expected:<[(10,100),(4,40),(5,50),(1,10),(2,20),(3,30)]>
Actual:<[(5,50),(4,40),(3,30),(1,10),(2,20),(10,100)]>

Assert failed.
Expected:<[(9,90),(7,70),(8,80),(6,60),(2,20),(1,10),(3,30),(5,50)]>
Actual:<[(9,90),(7,70),(8,80),(5,50),(2,20),(1,10),(3,30),(6,60)]>

Assert failed.
Expected:<[(6,60),(5,50),(4,40),(1,10),(2,20),(3,30)]>
Actual:<[(6,60),(5,50),(3,30),(1,10),(2,20),(4,40)]>

My insert function is :

```
void insert(KeyValueType const& keyValue)
    {

        size_t asize = size();
        if (asize == 0)
        {
            table.push_back(keyValue);
        }
        else
        {
            table.push_back(keyValue);
            for (int i = asize / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                heapify(i);

            }
        }
    }
```

and my heapify function is :

```
void heapify(size_t index)
    {
        auto previous_index = index;
        do
        {
            previous_index = index;
            auto largest = getLargestFromParentAndHisChildren(index);
            if (index != largest)
            {
                std::swap(table[index], table[largest]);
                index = largest;
            }
        } while (index != previous_index);
    }
```

Comment: Is this homework? The Standard Library provides heap functions.

Comment: Recommendation: Wrap this up in a [mre] that reproduces the unwanted behaviour. If you figure out the problem before you finish the MRE, do what you will (but I recommend self-answering); otherwise, replace the code in the question with the MRE so people out here can (within the bounds of what undefined behaviour allows) see exactly what you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop starts at the wrong value. It should be:

```
for (int i = (asize - 1) / 2; i >= 0; i--)
```

Not your question, but:

- calling `heapify` is not the fastest way to bubble a value up, since that function needs to check also the sibling value, which is unnecessary.
- `i--` will make this loop O(n), which is not the complexity you would want for a heap. This operation should be O(logn), and so `i` should jump from child to parent, in each iteration.
- Moreover, when the previous point is implemented, this loop could exit when no more swap occurs.